# @testing-library/react-hooks 'act' function show me 'no floating promises' lint error

Tags: typescript, eslint, react-hooks-testing-library

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useRefWithSetter from '../useRefWithSetter'

describe('Test useRefWithSetter', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useRefWithSetter(1))

  const [valueRef, setValue] = result.current

  test('you can return value through setter function', () => {
    act(() => {
      setValue(2)
    })

    expect(valueRef.current).toBe(2)
  })

  test('you can return callback function through setter function', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      setValue((prev) => prev + 3)

      return Promise.resolve()
    })

    expect(valueRef.current).toBe(5)
  })
})
```

***Error message : [eslint @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises] [E] Promises must be handled appropiately or explicitly marked as ignored the void operator. (@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)***

Hello.
I'm trying to test my customized hook but I don't know how to use 'act' function from react-hooks-testing-library. It shows lint error so I was trying to fix like second test but I don't think it's appropriate way because that hook is not Promise function. Is there any way to explicitly mark as ignored with the `void` operator?

Comment: Hi, don't post code as images, put your code in your question directly.

Comment: @Celsiuss Thank you for your advice! This is my first question so I didn't know about that.

Comment: I have the same error. Have you managed to fix this? Docs say: `Wrapping incrementAsync in act() is not necessary since the state updates happen asynchronously during await waitForNextUpdate().` But it still needs `act` and ESLint complains.

Comment: @igor Hello, I changed some code and it turns out to work for me.
`test('you can return value through setter function', () => {
    ;(act as Function)(() => {
      setValue(2)
    })

    expect(valueRef.current).toBe(2)
  })`

Comment: `void act(() => { ...}` works for me

Comment: `void act(() => { ...}` gives `no-void` error